# How to correctly use ROS and Eclipse

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am starting to use ROS with Eclipse and I with doubts about on how to build the source files. Should I do it from inside ** Eclipse**, should I do it with **catkin_make** or should I do it in **other way**. I am also starting with c++ and way kind of additional clarification is welcome.

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227787/how-to-correctly-use-ros-and-eclipse/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Complete instructions for using Eclipse with ROS can be found at the [ROS IDEs Wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse). For what it's worth, I've used both Eclipse and QtCreator with ROS and found QtCreator to be much easier to setup and use since it supports CMake projects by default. Instructions for using QtCreator can be found on that same page.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1